# pthreads, variables get erroneous

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pthreads

This is a code snippet, first time when I call FileServerStart() from main it works fine, when I call FileServerStart() from another function it gives an error ( Access violation writing location 0x6C706D61.) in cout statement, while mFileName is string defined as class variable. 
I tried making it static it gives an error, the characters get corrupted in the string, also I checked it I am not changing/assigning mFileName elsewhere, I am only assigning it in the constructor in the start and passing it as an argument at two different locations.
Also I tried assigning it before pthread_create(), gives a heap error.

```
int FileServer::FileServerStart()
{
    int rc;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    //mFileName = "C:\\Users\\Kamran Afridi\\Desktop\\sample"; //it is commented
    cout<<"File Server Start: "<<mFileName<<endl;
    rc = pthread_create(&mScanDirectoryThread, &attr, &FileServer::scanDirectoryStructure_helper, (void*)mFileName.c_str());
    pthread_join(mScanDirectoryThread, &status);
    return rc;
}

void *FileServer::scanDirectoryStructure_helper(void* faContext)
{
        return ((FileServer*) faContext)->scanDirectoryStructure_linux((FileServer*) faContext);
}
```

[image: mFileName when FileServerStart() is called from another function]

Comment: The `FileServer` object has either been destroyed or not been properly initialised before you use it.

Comment: @Kamran You pass `mFileName.c_str()`(`const char *`) via `pthread_create()`, but function `FileServer::scanDirectoryStructure_helper()` requires `FileServer*` type.